# Microsoft Word Templete VBA code is gone after logout/login

Tags: vba, ms-word

Does the Microsoft Word normal template update every time I log in/out?

I have not been able to figure out how to save my macros and quick parts. Every time I log out and get back in, they are gone.

I know how to import them back in but I want to know how to update my normal template in a way that won’t get undone every time I log out. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you save it in the `Normal.dotm` format? Because `.dotx` cannot contain VBA code. It gets stripped off if you save it. Note that you ned to **save** it as `.dotm` renaming the file does not work. And you need to write your VBA code again (it is gone if you saved as `dotx` once).

Comment: Not unless you are using a work pc where your company has a policy of replacing it at login. Word will replace it automatically if it detects that it is corrupt in some way. This makes storing code in Normal.dotm a risky practice, but the risks can be reduced if you regularly export the code modules. If you locate the Startup folder, typically %AppData%\Microsoft\Word\STARTUP, you can store a template in there to hold your Quick Parts/Building Blocks.

Comment: The default storage place for macros is the normal.dotm template. As a default, that is OK. As a place to deliberately store macros, not so good because funny *`things`* seem to happen to the normal.dotm template. As Timothy Rylatt said, you can store your macros in a separate global template. That is where I keep the bulk of the macros that I use regularly. I also regularly back up my normal template whenever I make a change. Here is a macro for doing that: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/backup-normaldotm-template-using-a-macro/81aea1ae-e31b-437e-ac4a-3ebf9b4f7b5f